# Es necesario instanciar clases de java para usar un solo metodo?

Tags: java

quisiera saber si es necesario instanciar una clase de java en una variable para usar uno solo de sus metodos. Por ej:
En lugar de usar:

```
Clase variable = new Clase();
metodoMio(variable.procesarTexto("null"));
```

usar:

```
metodoMio(new Clase().procesarTexto("null"));
```

¿Tendra impacto sobre el uso de la memoria y el rendimiento de mi aplicacion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es necesario, aunque puedes hacer un metodo estatico que no necesitaria instanciacion:

```
public class Clase {
    public static String procesadorTexto(String palabra){
        String palabraEditada = palabra;//editas lo que sea
        return palabraEditada;
    }
}
```

Para llamar al metodo:

```
metodoMio(Clase.procesadorTexto("loquesea"));
```

Comment: Excelente, disculpa la pregunta, ¿los metodos estaticos tienen menos impacto en el uso de la memoria?

Comment: Depende, pero si solo es para usar el metodo estatico si. Si haces una clase, depende de cuando se mande la clase al recolector de basura. Pero el caso que propones el impacto seria similar, ya que la clase solo vive en la llamada al metodo si lo haces asi: metodoMio(new Clase().procesarTexto("null"));

Comment: Muchas gracias Santiago me has ayudado bastante.

Comment: Los métodos estáticos sí tienen impacto los trata de manera diferente la JVM, si lo que querías era ahorrarte la línea entonces no lo hagas. En tus dos ejemplos al final tendrán el mismo impacto en recursos.